# Report Builder 3.0 using an interval on a chart axis with multiple categories

Tags: datetime, reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder3.0

I'm making a line chart with integers running along the y-axis and both an integer with a datetime inside it on the x-axis.

I want to know how to make the intervals work for the datetime value while keeping it in the integer group. Such as I want the interval for the datetime to be 15 minutes, however setting this with both categories on the axis does not work and the auto value gives seemingly random and inconsistent intervals.

Setting it to scalar fixes the intervals but removes the integer x-axis value.

Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT:
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1gcg.png) is when I have axis type scalar ticked, the shape of the line chart and the major tick lines make sense, however there is only one label on the x-axis.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fitvh.png) is when I have axis type category clicked, I have both labels on the x-axis like I want but the intervals become weird.

Comment: Are you trying to get two separate lines on the chart? If so, how do you determine the x-axis for the first line? Would you please provide some sample data as well?

Comment: Only one line on the chart, I will edit my question and add some screenshots.